# How do I avoid excessively using OR?

Tags: lua

Here is my code:

```
repeat

  ...

  print("would you like to do that again?")
  answer = io.read()
until answer == "no" or answer == "n" or answer == "nope"
```

Obviously the use of "nope" is trite but the point holds: how do I avoid using OR too much? Is there a way to put all possible comparison values in a list and compare said list to a given string?

Comment: Your code is simple and efficient. No need to complicate it.

Comment: you can do negative logic (until answer!="yes") - this way everything is a "no" unless its a "yes".

Comment: @Lawrence, but then I guess he'd want "y" and "yep" as variants of "yes"...

Comment: @Ihf, that depends on the approach. But you are most likely right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As lhf says, the code you presented is pretty simple. But if you are doing this for several sets of words, or for larger sets, you might want to use Lua tables as sets. Here's an example:

```
is_no = { ["no"]= true; ["n"]= true; ["nope"]= true; }


repeat
  -- ...
  print("would you like to do that again?")
  answer = io.read()
until is_no[answer]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a function to handle the list so for example

```
function inList(value,list)
  value  = value:lower()
  for k,v in ipairs(list) do
    if v == value then
            return true
    end
  end
  return false
end

print(inList('yes',{'no','nope','n'}))

if inList('No',{'no','nope','n'}) then
    print('Is in List')
end
```

It's more processor hungry than the simple OR statements you have already,  but might be easier if you needed to process lots of variations.  I included the :lower command so No, NOPE etc would also return true.